# Help with anti-disassembly trick inside a hooked function

Tags: ida, anti-debugging, function-hooking

I am trying to understand a hook installed by a program within the Win32 API function ZwWriteVirtualMemory.

It seems that a jmp inside an instruction is used and I couldn't fix  it to be able to continue my analysis.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated !

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no obfuscation here, it is a fairly standard jump to a fixed address.

Breaking it down:

```
FF 25 00 00 00 00        ; jmp  qword ptr [rip]
68 01 4A 00 00 00 00 00  ; dq   00000004A0168h
```

The first instruction says to read the value at RIP and then jump to that address. Since RIP is already advanced past the end of the instruction, the data value is in the 8 bytes following the jump (which happens to be the value 0x4A0168). So the code that executes next is at that virtual address.

Comment: And the value following the jump is in little-endian ? How can I easily tell IDA to follow the jump ?